# Passing objects to methods java

Tags: java

I'm using three objects: `StringBuilder`, `Integer`, and `testobject` - that are passed to a method to change its state.

As expected, the `StringBuilder` and `testobject` points to the same object and the state is change but it does not work for `Integer` object.

```
class testobject{
    int x = 1;
}

public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("String");
        go(s1);
        System.out.println(s1);

        Integer s2 = new Integer("20");
        go1(s2);
        System.out.println(s2);

        testobject s3 = new testobject();
        go2(s3);
        System.out.println(s3.x);
    }

    static void go(StringBuilder s1){
        s1.append("Builder");
    }

    static void go1(Integer s2){
        s2 = 1;
    }
    static void go2(testobject s3){
        s3.x = 5;
    }
```

Result:

```
StringBuilder
20
5
```

ExpectedResult:

```
StringBuilder
1
5
```

Comment: `Integer` objects are immutable. By trying to assign it to a new number, you are creating a new object.

Comment: Nothing is passed by reference in Java. (In the case of objects, they're reference types, passed by value.)

Answer (score 9):

Look at your three methods:

```
static void go(StringBuilder s1){
    s1.append("Builder");
}

static void go1(Integer s2){
    s2 = 1;
}

static void go2(testobject s3){
    s3.x = 5;
}
```

In `go` and `go2`, you're making a modification to the object that the parameter value refers to.

In `go1`, you're changing the value of the parameter variable itself. That's very different, and because [Java always uses pass-by-value](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm), that change isn't seen by the caller.

It's important to understand that *objects* aren't passed to the methods at all. Instead, references are. The value of `s1`, `s2` and `s3` are all references. If you think of the variables as like pieces of paper, each piece of paper has a house address on it, which was copied from a piece of paper declared in `main`.

The method bodies of `go` and `go2` are like visiting the house whose address is on the piece of paper, and painting the front door. If you then visit the houses using the *original* pieces of paper, you still see the new colours on the front doors.

The method body of `go1` is like scribbling out the address written on the piece of paper, and writing a new one on there instead. That doesn't make any change to a house, nor does it change the original piece of paper.

Comment: @Jon-- I don't need to remember this..its well explained

Comment: @user1050619: I'm not sure what you mean. You absolutely *do* need to remember this... it's a fundamental part of Java.

Comment: Would it make a difference if we initialize the object like `Integer s2 = new Integer(20)`, because I can see there are two constructors for it, one accepting a `String` and another an `int` as shown here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Answer (score -1):

If the argument you want to pass is an object instead a of primitive type, then Java treats pass by object as pass by value, because Java supports a **pass-by-value** concept.

Here a and p are the same reference:

```
public class ObjPass {
    int value;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjPass p = new ObjPass();
        p.value = 5;
        System.out.println("Before calling: " + p.value);
        increment(p);
        System.out.println("After calling: " + p.value);       
    }
    public static void increment(ObjPass a){
        a.value++;

    }

}
```

Output:

```
Before calling: 5
After calling: 6
```